# Solve $\frac{25-\frac{x}{3}}{x+1}+\frac{16x+4\frac{1}{5}}{3x+2}=5+\frac{23}{x+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve $\dfrac{25-\frac{x}{3}}{x+1}+\dfrac{16x+4\frac{1}{5}}{3x+2}=5+\dfrac{23}{x+1}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{25}{x+1}-\dfrac{x}{3(x+1)}+\dfrac{16x}{3x+2}+\dfrac{21}{5(3x+2)}=5+\dfrac{23}{x+1} \ \ \ ...(1)$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{25}{x+1}-\dfrac{23}{x+1}-\dfrac{x}{3(x+1)}+\dfrac{16x}{3x+2}+\dfrac{20}{5(3x+2)}+\dfrac{1}{5(3x+2)}=5 \ \ \ ...(2)$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{2}{x+1}-\dfrac{x}{3(x+1)}+\dfrac{16x+4}{3x+2}+\dfrac{1}{5(3x+2)}=5 \ \ \ ...(3)$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{2}{x+1}-\dfrac{x}{3(x+1)}+\dfrac{3x+2+3x+2+10x}{3x+2}+\dfrac{1}{5(3x+2)}=5 \ \ \ ...(4)$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{2}{x+1}-\dfrac{x}{3(x+1)}+2+\dfrac{10x}{3x+2}+\dfrac{1}{5(3x+2)}=5 \ \ \ ...(5)$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{2}{x+1}-\dfrac{x}{3(x+1)}+\dfrac{10x}{3x+2}+\dfrac{1}{5(3x+2)}=3 \ \ \ ...(6)$

From here I could conceivably just brute force calculate the answer, but it seems too tedious and crude. Is there more simplifications to be made, or any I missed in earlier steps? Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Do not keep fractions, just multiply the whole thing by $15(x+1)(3x+2)$ and simplify.

Comment: simplify further: $\dfrac{2}{x+1}-\dfrac{x}{3(x+1)}=\dfrac{5x+6}{3(x+1)}; \dfrac{10x}{3x+2}+\dfrac{1}{5(3x+2)}=\dfrac{150x^2+100x+1}{5(3x+2)};$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{25-\frac{x}{3}}{x+1}+\dfrac{16x+4\frac{1}{5}}{3x+2}=5+\dfrac{23}{x+1}$

Multiplicate $15(x+1)(3x+2)$ to each sides

$\Rightarrow 5(75-x)(3x+2)+3(80x+21)(x+1)=75(x+1)(3x+2)+345(3x+2)$

$\Rightarrow -15x^2+1125x-10x+750+240x^2+303x+63=225x^2+375x+150+1035x+690$

$\Rightarrow x=\frac{27}{8}$

Answer (score 0):

I would start simplifying in the following way:

1. Move the last term from the right hand side to the beginning
   $$\frac{25-23-\frac x3}{x+1}+\frac{16x+\frac{21}5}{3x+2}=5$$
2. Notice that some fraction can be simplified $$\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}=\frac{\frac ac(cx+d)-\frac{ad}{c}+b}{cx+d}=\frac ac+\frac{-\frac{ad}c+b}{cx+d}$$

You will then have at most a quadratic equation in $x$